# addEventListener for clicking button fires twice - JS for google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My button click listener somehow fires twice.

Here is the code in my popup.js file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
  
  submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var textInput = document.getElementById('textInput');
    var text = textInput.value;

    console.log('I am in submitButton listener');
  });
});
```

When I click the button - it's being called twice. I checked and don't have any more listeners that handle clicks on this button across all my project.

The button is on the popup.html file. Here is how the button looks like in HTML:

```
<body>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>Enter your text and click the "Send" button</p>
  <div>
    <textarea id="textInput" placeholder="Enter text"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button id="submitButton">Send</button>
  </div>
  <div class="result" id="result"></div>
</body>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Perhaps the script is imported twice? May you check from the "Event Listeners" panel in Dev tools for that element? Have you tried to increment an integer and log it for test? Does it yields `0` `0` or `0` `1`? There's many things you can try to debug this issue

Comment: There's some missing information: where, for example, is the button - is it on the page the extension is working on, in an extension popup...? What type of button is it? Is it `type=" button" or `type="submit"`, something else? You should add any relevant markup to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I see double clicks here as well: https://monosnap.com/file/wFiryOOaLO0rO8hwvhcZEfoVdTSWfL

Comment: @Andy I added the information, thank you. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Based on that screenshot Roko maybe right. The script looks like it's being loaded twice. @RikkiTikkiTavi

Comment: where can I check that it was imported twice? @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: Are you perhaps loading it both in the manifest, and as a `<script>` call within the popup HTML? @RikkiTikkiTavi

Comment: @Andy thank you very much! Yes, I added the script both at the top and the bottom of the popup.html file. That resolved the issue!